# How to solve Shape error in Human 3D fall detection using Computer Vision

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, data-science

I'm following this Git-hub repository (Link: https://github.com/JJN123/Fall-Detection)

as per repository i run `dstcae_c3d_main_train.py` python file but got an error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv3d_7 to have shape (4, 64, 64, 1) but got array with shape (2, 64, 64, 1)
```

please helping me out, how to give an input to train model for 3D fall detection.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you should try to contact the author of the code.